# delete string date on database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-delete

I have a table (db_dates) with three columns (id, datetime and name_date).

I want to delete one row, when the date is over, such likes this:

```
//select string time from database
$selectTime ="SELECT datetime FROM db_dates";
$timeSelect = mysqli_query($con,$selectTime);

//today 
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i');
printf ("today: %s \n",$today);

//get one date from database    
while($rowTime = mysqli_fetch_row($timeSelect)){    
  $date = new DateTime($rowTime[0]);
  $t = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
  printf ("date: %s \n",$t);    

  //delete this row, when the date is over 
  mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM db_dates WHERE '".$rowTime[0]."' < '".$today."'");
}
```

Not working, how do I do that? It is always deleted all data!

Comment: I prefer to use sql only. How about just run `mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM db_dates WHERE datetime < now()");` this will select all rows which `datetime < today`

Comment: Your delete will remove all records from db_dates if there is an entry with rowTime < today, because you compare the value and not the field. You'll end up with a where clause like this: `WHERE '2016-11-19 10:00:00' < '2016-11-19 11:16:00'` and that is true for every row.

Comment: thank you for all answers. The Problem is, now() has a different format?

Comment: thank you #Quagaar, but if I have a value such as '2017-10-2 11:30'?? Then it is not over yet!

Comment: i found the solution: mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM db_dates WHERE datetime < NOW()");   thank you #developer

Answer (score 0):

**I think this will help you.**

Because as per your code date will be always less then today's date the way you are getting.

So you should try below code using `DATEDIFF()`.

```
//select string time from database
$selectTime ="SELECT datetime FROM db_dates";
$timeSelect = mysqli_query($con,$selectTime);

//today 
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i');
printf ("today: %s \n",$today);

//get one date from database    
while($rowTime = mysqli_fetch_row($timeSelect)){    
  $date = new DateTime($rowTime[0]);
  $t = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
  printf ("date: %s \n",$t);    
  //delete this row, when the date is over 
  mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM db_dates WHERE DATEDIFF('".$rowTime[0]."', NOW()) < 0");
}
```

Comment: `echo DELETE FROM db_dates WHERE DATEDIFF('".$rowTime[0]."', NOW()) < 0";` and check what query is made